# Custom login/registration pages for force.com site

Tags: authentication, login, session, user-registration

**Hello!** I am developing a website as an online shop, and I encountered a problem with login and registration. I created portal with Authenticated Website license, which is assigned to site. I enable self-registration there. Also, I have created an account for registration and contacts with self-registration enabled. Then I used this account id to override it in the SiteRegister controller. But I am still not able to register a new user on the website either by using account email, some random email, contact email. 
I really need to solve this problem, because when I create some custom login page user login data is not maintained on all site pages. 
In what way can I resolve such a problem? *Your help will be appreciated!*

Comment: Can you check if your Site is active ?

Comment: I activated it, and near the site name there is only deactivate and edit actions. Can you tell me how else can I check it?

Comment: I am not sure what is messed up in your config. Please go through this document - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_customer_portal_setup.htm&language=en&type=0 and this one - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_login_and_registration_settings.htm&language=en&type=0